# Getting random object in AsyncStorage in React Native with Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Hello all I am building an application using `react-native` in that I am using redux while authentication I am stuck at some place I am getting token as random object below is my code

**---Reducer---**

```js
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAIL, LOGOUT_SUCCESS } from '../actions/type';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const initialState = {
    token: AsyncStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated: false,
    isLoading: true
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            AsyncStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                isLoading: false,
            };
        case LOGIN_FAIL:
        case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
            AsyncStorage.removeItem('token');
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload,
                token: null,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                isLoading: false,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**---Action---**

```js
axios.post(api_url+'login', formdata, config)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log("res",res.data)
        if(res.data.status == "true") {            
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data.data,
            });
            dispatch(returnMsg(res.data.msg,res.data.status))
        }
        if(res.data.status == "false") {
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_FAIL,
                payload: res.data,
            });
            dispatch(returnMsg(res.data.msg,res.data.status))
        }        
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
});
```

I am calling the reducer in app for checking token below is the code

```js
const actiondata = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
const {token} = actiondata;
console.log(token);
```

this is the random token value i get when i console it
"{"_h": 0, "_i": 1, "_j": null, "_k": null}"

Answer (score 3):

AsyncStorage.getItem is an async call and needs to be awaited. The object you're getting back is a pending promise.

Answer (score 0):

Your actiondata is returning a promise(which is in pending state). Here what you should do

```
const {token} = await actiondata;
console.log(token);
```

It will print out your token value if promise gets fullfiled.